# CSS and form input:text not showing input text

Tags: css, forms, textinput

I am trying to make an input form have a background image, but as soon as I apply the CSS class to the input, the default value does not show up (it does work if there is no CSS class applied). Here is the HTML:

```
<form>
     <input type="text" class="emailInput" value="Enter your email address">
     <input type="submit" class="emailBtn" value="">
</form>
```

And here is the CSS that is associated with it:

```
input.emailInput {
color:#000;
background:url('images/emailBackground.png') no-repeat;
display:block;
width:313px;
height:31px;
text-indent:-5000px;
position:relative;
top:0px;
left:-2px;
border:none;
}
input.emailBtn {
background:url('images/emailBtn.png') no-repeat;
display:block;
width:55px;
height:38px;
text-indent:-5000px;
position:relative;
top:-32px;
left:323px;
border:none;
}
```

I am at a total loss. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Perhaps the `text-indent:-5000px;` is causing your text to be positioned out of the visible area.

Comment: Further to this, use IE dev tools or Firebug in Firefox to inspect the CSS. You can then remove the indent to see if this is causing the problem.

Comment: Thanks, This is exactly the problem. I looked at this at least 20 times and totally overlooked it every time. I had just pasted from another element where I had the text-indent:-5000px;. I will sheepishly walk away. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

This is just as hunch, but I'm pretty sure your problem is `text-indent:-5000px;`. Considering your text input elements are much smaller in width than the value set there.

Also, just as a point of note:

http://luigimontanez.com/2010/stop-using-text-indent-css-trick/

So you don't want to use that anyway if you want your page to play nice with Google.